# changing datetime format with strptime

Tags: python, datetime, formatting, strptime

I'm trying to add or minus time from a datetime object and then convert it to strptime but I'm getting an error message.

Here's an example of getting the 'hour' of a datetime object, adding + 1 to it and then trying to use strptime on it;

```
time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("09/Sep/2015:08:00:00", "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")

print time1.hour
print time1.hour + 1

> 8
  9

time3 = time1.hour + 1
print time3.strptime('%H')

> print time3.strptime('%H')
 AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'strptime'
```

Is there any way to manipulate datetime objects and change its format (with strptime or similar)?

Comment: This is what the datetime.timedelta objects are for. Adding them to a datetime.datetime will return another datetime.datetime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`time1.hour` is an `int`, `1` is an `int`, therfore `time3` is an `int`, which is why you are getting this error.

You should also use `strftime` in your last line, not `strptime`.

You can use `relativedelta` or `timedelta` (see the comments), but I suppose that `datetime.replace` will be easier:

```
time1 = datetime.datetime.strptime("09/Sep/2015:08:00:00", "%d/%b/%Y:%H:%M:%S")

time3 = time1.replace(hour=time1.hour + 1)
print time3.strftime('%H')
>> 09
```

**EDIT** This will indeed fail for times after `23:00`. Use the recommended approaches in the comments for a more robust solution.

Comment: Alternatively, one can use timedelta: `time3 = time1 + datetime.timedelta(hours=1)`

Comment: I recommend using delta objects for arithmetic operations and using the replace method more like a setter (datetimes are immutable)

Comment: @vrs The problem with that is that it will return '9' instead of '09'. That's why I need strftime to work on it.

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for!

Comment: `time1.replace(hour=time1.hour + 1)` will fail for times after 11 pm. Use `time1 + timedelta.delta(hours=1)` instead, then format the result with `strftime()`.

Comment: @user1165419 I don't mind using `time3.strftime('%H')`, I just recommend using `timedelta` instead of `replace` for the style sake (see what @code_onkel says above)